# Displaying form validation next to input fields

Tags: php, mysql, database, forms, validation

I'm trying to display the PHP span errors next to my input fields, however after the first line op span error, the other input fields disappear..

How can I make the other input fields visible again so that the error messages will be displayed next to them?

```
<body ontouchmove="BlockMove(event);">
    <div class="container">

        <div class="st-container">
            <input type="radio" name="radio-set" checked="checked" id="st-control-1" class="menu"/>
            <a href="#st-panel-1">Start</a>
            <input type="radio" name="radio-set" id="st-control-2" class="menu"/>
            <a href="#st-panel-2">Vraag 1</a>
            <input type="radio" name="radio-set" id="st-control-3" class="menu"/>
            <a href="#st-panel-3">Vraag 2</a>
            <input type="radio" name="radio-set" id="st-control-4" class="menu"/>
            <a href="#st-panel-4">De uitdaging</a>

            <div class="st-scroll">

                <section class="st-panel" id="st-panel-1">
                    <div class="st-deco"></div>
                    <div id="position">
                        <div id="contact">
                            <div id="bevestiging">
                                <div id="midden">
                                    <div id="formulierruimte">
                                    <?php
                                        require_once("php/db.php");                 /* Database Class */
                                        require_once('php/utils/is_email.php');     /* Email Validation Script */

                                        /* Handle Ajax Request */
                                        if(isset($_POST['newcontact'])){
                                            $contact = new Contact();
                                            //We'll refer to that later on, to display errors.
                                            //unset($contact);
                                        }
                                        else{
                                            //header('Location: result.php');
                                        }

                                        /* Class Contact */
                                        class Contact{

                                            private $db;                        /* the database obj */

                                            //private $errors         = array();  /* holds error messages */
                                            //we have to init $errors array, as otherwise form will produce errors on missing array entry
                                            private $errors = array(            /* holds error messages */
                                                        'aanhef' => '',
                                                        'bedrijfsnaam' => '',
                                                        'email' => '',
                                                        'telefoon' => '',
                                                        'vraag1_antwoorden' => '',
                                                        'vraag2_antwoorden' => ''
                                                    );


                                            private $num_errors;                /* number of errors in submitted form */

                                            public function __construct(){
                                                $this->db = new DB();
                                                if(isset($_POST['newcontact']))
                                                    $this->processNewMessage();
                                                /* We don't need this anymore
                                                 * 
                                                else
                                                    header('Location: result.php');*/
                                            }

                                            public function processNewMessage(){

                                                $aanhef             = $_POST['aanhef'];         
                                                $contactpersoon     = $_POST['contactpersoon'];     
                                                $bedrijfsnaam       = $_POST['bedrijfsnaam'];
                                                $telefoon           = $_POST['telefoon'];
                                                $email              = $_POST['email'];
                                                $vraag1_antwoorden  = $_POST['vraag1_antwoorden'];
                                                $vraag2_antwoorden  = $_POST['vraag2_antwoorden'];


                                                /* Server Side Data Validation */

                                                /* Aanhef Validation */
                                                if(!$aanhef || mb_strlen($aanhef = trim($aanhef)) == 0)
                                                    $this->setError('aanhef', 'Selecteer uw aanhef');

                                                /* Contactpersoon Validation */
                                                if(!$contactpersoon || mb_strlen($contactpersoon = trim($contactpersoon)) == 0)
                                                    $this->setError('contactpersoon', 'Vul uw contactpersoon in');
                                                else if(mb_strlen(trim($contactpersoon)) > 120)
                                                    $this->setError('contactpersoon', 'Te lang! 120 karakters max.');

                                                /* Bedrijfsnaam Validation */
                                                    if(!$bedrijfsnaam || mb_strlen($bedrijfsnaam = trim($bedrijfsnaam)) == 0)
                                                    $this->setError('bedrijfsnaam', 'Vul uw bedrijfsnaam in');
                                                else if(mb_strlen(trim($bedrijfsnaam)) > 120)
                                                    $this->setError('bedrijfsnaam', 'Te lang! 120 karakters max.');

                                                    /* Telefoon Validation */
                                                    if(!$telefoon || mb_strlen($telefoon = trim($telefoon)) == 0)
                                                    $this->setError('telefoon', 'Vul uw telefoonnummer in');
                                                else if(mb_strlen(trim($telefoon)) > 120)
                                                    $this->setError('telefoon', 'Te lang! 120 karakters max.');

                                                    /* Vraag 1 Validation */
                                                    if(!$vraag1_antwoorden || mb_strlen($vraag1_antwoorden = trim($vraag1_antwoorden)) == 0)
                                                    $this->setError('vraag1_antwoorden', 'Selecteer een antwoord a.u.b.');

                                                    /* Vraag 2 Validation */
                                                    if(!$vraag2_antwoorden || mb_strlen($vraag2_antwoorden = trim($vraag2_antwoorden)) == 0)
                                                    $this->setError('vraag2_antwoorden', 'Selecteer een antwoord a.u.b.');

                                                    /* Email Validation */
                                                if(!$email || mb_strlen($email = trim($email)) == 0)
                                                    $this->setError('email','Vul uw e-mail in');
                                                else{
                                                    if(!is_email($email))
                                                        $this->setError('email', 'Vul een correct email adres in');
                                                    else if(mb_strlen($email) > 120)
                                                        $this->setError('email', 'Te lang! 120 karakters max.');
                                                }

                                                /* No errors, insert in db
                                                else*/
                                                if($this->countErrors() == 0) {
                                                    if(($ret = $this->db->dbNewMessage($aanhef, $contactpersoon, $bedrijfsnaam, $email, $telefoon, $vraag1_antwoorden, $vraag2_antwoorden)) > 0){
                                                        //$json = array('result'         => 1);
                                                        if(SEND_EMAIL)
                                                            $this->sendEmail($aanhef,$contactpersoon,$bedrijfsnaam,$email,$telefoon,$vraag1_antwoorden,$vraag2_antwoorden);

                                                        //This is for relocating to successful result page
                                                        header('Location: result.php');
                                                    } else {   
                                                        // else
                                                        //    $json = array('result'      => -2); /* something went wrong in database insertion  */

                                                        //This will need special treatment. You have to prepare an errorpage
                                                        //for database-related issues.
                                                        header("Location: database-error.html");
                                                    }

                                                    /*$encoded = json_encode($json);
                                                    echo $encoded;
                                                    unset($encoded);*/
                                                }
                                            }

                                            public function sendEmail($aanhef,$contactpersoon,$bedrijfsnaam,$email,$telefoon,$vraag1_antwoorden,$vraag2_antwoorden){
                                            /* Just format the email text the way you want ... */
                                            $message_body   = "<div style=\"font-size:12px; font-weight:normal;\">Hallo,<br><br>"
                                                                        ."Het volgende bedrijf heeft zich zojuist aangemeld:</div><br>"
                                                                        ."<table cellpadding=\"1\" cellspacing=\"1\" width=\"550px\"><tr><td style=\"font-size:12px; color:#000000\">Bedrijfsnaam:</td><td style=\"font-size:12px; color:#000000\">".$bedrijfsnaam."</td></tr><tr><td style=\"font-size:12px; color:#000000\">Aanhef:</td><td style=\"font-size:12px; color:#000000\">".$aanhef."</td></tr><tr><td style=\"font-size:12px; color:#000000\">Contactpersoon:</td><td style=\"font-size:12px; color:#000000\">".$contactpersoon."</td></tr><tr><td style=\"font-size:12px; color:#000000\">Telefoonnummer:</td><td style=\"font-size:12px; color:#000000\">".$telefoon."</td></tr><tr><td style=\"font-size:12px; color:#000000\">E-mail:</td><td style=\"font-size:12px; color:#000000\">".$email."</td></tr><tr><td style=\"font-size:12px; color:#000000\">Antwoord vraag 1:</td><td style=\"font-size:12px; color:#000000\">".$vraag1_antwoorden."</td></tr><tr><td style=\"font-size:12px; color:#000000\">Antwoord vraag 2:</td><td style=\"font-size:12px; color:#000000\">".$vraag2_antwoorden."</td></tr></table><br>";

                                                // Geef GELDIGE adressen op
                                                // Een korte benaming voor jouw website
                                                $website_naam = 'Aanmelding';
                                                // Jouw eigen geldige emailadres
                                                $eigen_emailadres = 'MAIL';
                                                // Een geldig emailadres voor errors
                                                $error_emailadres = 'MAIL';
                                                // De naam van de verzender
                                                $naam_verzender = ''.$bedrijfsnaam.'';
                                                // Het geldige emailadres van de afzender
                                                $email_verzender = ''.$email.'';
                                                // Een geldig emailadres of helemaal leeg laten
                                                $bcc_emailadres = '';
                                                // HTML mail? True/False
                                                $html = true;

                                                // De headers samenstellen
                                                $headers     = 'From: ' . $website_naam . ' <' . $eigen_emailadres . '>' . PHP_EOL;
                                                $headers    .= 'Reply-To: ' . $naam_verzender . ' <' . $email_verzender . '>' . PHP_EOL;
                                                $headers    .= 'Return-Path: Mail-Error <' . $error_emailadres . '>' . PHP_EOL;
                                                $headers    .= ($bcc_emailadres != '') ? 'Bcc: ' . $bcc_emailadres . PHP_EOL : '';
                                                $headers    .= 'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion() . PHP_EOL;
                                                $headers    .= 'X-Priority: Normal' . PHP_EOL;
                                                $headers    .= ($html) ? 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . PHP_EOL : '';
                                                $headers    .= ($html) ? 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . PHP_EOL : '';


                                                mail(EMAIL_TO,MESSAGE_SUBJECT,$message_body,$headers);

                                            }

                                            public function setError($field, $errmsg){
                                                $this->errors[$field]   = $errmsg;
                                                $this->num_errors       = count($this->errors);
                                            }

                                            public function error_value($field){
                                                if(array_key_exists($field,$this->errors))
                                                    return $this->errors[$field];
                                                else
                                                    return '';
                                            }

                                            public function countErrors(){
                                                return $this->num_errors;
                                            }
                                        };
                                        ?>
                                        <table width="675px" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                            <form id="ContactForm" action="quiz.php" method="post">
                                            <tr>
                                                <td class="left_td">&nbsp;</td><td><font size="-2">* Gelieve alle velden in te vullen.</font></td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr class="rij_aanhef">
                                                <td class="left_td">Aanhef<font size="-2" style="vertical-align:top;">*</font></td>
                                                <td>
                                                    <label class="label_aanhef" for="aanhef_1"><input name="aanhef" id="aanhef_1" value="Dhr." type="radio" /> Dhr.</label><label class="label_aanhef" for="aanhef_2"><input name="aanhef" id="aanhef_2" value="Mevr." type="radio" /> Mevr.</label>
                                                    <span class="error" style="display:none; margin-left:40px;">
                                                        <?php echo($contact->error_value("'aanhef'")) ?>
                                                    </span>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr class="rij_contactpersoon">
                                                <td class="left_td">Contactpersoon</td>
                                                <td>
                                                    <input id="contactpersoon" name="contactpersoon" class="inplaceError" maxlength="120" type="text" class="error" autocomplete="off" onFocus="window.scrollTo(0, 0);"/>
                                                    <span class="error" style="display:none; margin-left:40px;">
                                                        <?php echo($contact->error_value('contactpersoon')) ?>
                                                    </span>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr class="rij_bedrijf">
                                                <td class="left_td">Bedrijfsnaam</td>
                                                <td>
                                                    <input id="bedrijfsnaam" name="bedrijfsnaam" class="inplaceError" maxlength="120" type="text" autocomplete="off" onFocus="window.scrollTo(0, 0);"/>
                                                    <span class="error" style="display:none; margin-left:40px;">
                                                        <?php echo($contact->error_value('bedrijfsnaam')) ?>
                                                    </span>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td class="left_td">E-mail</td>
                                                <td>
                                                    <input id="email" name="email" class="inplaceError" maxlength="120" type="text" autocomplete="off" onFocus="window.scrollTo(0, 0);"/>
                                                    <span class="error" style="display:none; margin-left:40px;">
                                                        <?php echo($contact->error_value('email')) ?>
                                                    </span>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td class="left_td">Telefoonnummer</td>
                                                <td><input id="telefoon" name="telefoon" class="inplaceError" maxlength="120" type="text" autocomplete="off" onFocus="window.scrollTo(0, 0);"/>
                                                    <span class="error" style="display:none; margin-left:40px;">
                                                        <?php echo($contact->error_value('telefoon')) ?>
                                                    </span>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </table>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </section>
            </div><!-- // st-scroll -->
            <div class="st-scroll">

                <section class="st-panel" id="st-panel-2">
                    <div class="st-deco"></div>
                        <h2>Toelichting:<br />Neem plaats op de eerste tegel en wek energie op. Zodra de vraag op het scherm verschijnt, kiest u één van de vier volgende antwoorden.</h2>
                            <div class="sizer">
                                <label class="label_radio" for="vraag1_A"><input name="vraag1_antwoorden" id="vraag1_A" value="A. Dat is helaas fout, het goede antwoord is: C) 1 Ohm" type="radio" />A) Geen eis</label>
                                <label class="label_radio" for="vraag1_B"><input name="vraag1_antwoorden" id="vraag1_B" value="B. Dat is helaas fout, het goede antwoord is: C) 1 Ohm" type="radio" />B) 0,1 Ohm</label>
                                <label class="label_radio" for="vraag1_C"><input name="vraag1_antwoorden" id="vraag1_C" value="C. Gefeliciteerd dat is het goede antwoord." type="radio" />C) 1 Ohm</label>
                                <label class="label_radio" for="vraag1_D"><input name="vraag1_antwoorden" id="vraag1_D" value="D. Dat is helaas fout, het goede antwoord is: C) 1 Ohm" type="radio" />D) 10 Ohm</label>
                            </div>
                            <span id="vraag1_antwoorden" class="foutmelding_quiz" style="display:none;">
                                <?php echo($contact->error_value('vraag1_antwoorden')) ?>
                            </span>
                </section>
            </div><!-- // st-scroll -->
            <div class="st-scroll">

                <section class="st-panel" id="st-panel-3">
                    <div class="st-deco"></div>
                        <h2>Toelichting:<br />Neem plaats op de tweede tegel en wek energie op. Zodra de vraag op het scherm verschijnt, kiest u één van de vier volgende antwoorden.</h2>
                            <div class="sizer">
                                <label class="label_radio" for="vraag2_A"><input name="vraag2_antwoorden" id="vraag2_A" value="A. Gefeliciteerd dat is het goede antwoord." type="radio" />A) 10 Ohm</label>
                                <label class="label_radio" for="vraag2_B"><input name="vraag2_antwoorden" id="vraag2_B" value="B. Dat is helaas fout, het goede antwoord is: A) 10 Ohm" type="radio" />B) 1 Ohm</label>
                                <label class="label_radio" for="vraag2_C"><input name="vraag2_antwoorden" id="vraag2_C" value="C. Dat is helaas fout, het goede antwoord is: A) 10 Ohm" type="radio" />C) 0,1 Ohm</label>
                                <label class="label_radio" for="vraag2_D"><input name="vraag2_antwoorden" id="vraag2_D" value="D. Dat is helaas fout, het goede antwoord is: A) 10 Ohm" type="radio" />D) Geen eis</label>
                            </div>
                            <span id="vraag2_antwoorden" class="foutmelding_quiz" style="display:none;">
                                <?php echo($contact->error_value('vraag2_antwoorden')) ?>
                            </span>
                </section>
            </div><!-- // st-scroll -->
            <div class="st-scroll">

                <section class="st-panel" id="st-panel-4">
                    <div class="st-deco"></div>
                        <h2>Toelichting:<br />Neem plaats op de derde tegel en zorg ervoor dat u genoeg energie opwekt om de balk tot 100% te laten komen.</h2>
                    <p>
                        <br /><br /><input type="submit" class="verzenden_image" value="" /><input type="hidden" id="newcontact" name="newcontact" value="1"></input></form>                         
                    </p>
                </section>
            </div><!-- // st-scroll -->

        </div><!-- // st-container -->
    </div>
    <!-- The JavaScript -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        function setupLabel() {
            if ($('.label_check input').length) {
                $('.label_check').each(function(){ 
                    $(this).removeClass('c_on');
                });
                $('.label_check input:checked').each(function(){ 
                    $(this).parent('label').addClass('c_on');
                });                
            };
            if ($('.label_radio input').length) {
                $('.label_radio').each(function(){ 
                    $(this).removeClass('r_on');
                });
                $('.label_radio input:checked').each(function(){ 
                    $(this).parent('label').addClass('r_on');
                });
            };
        };
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('body').addClass('has-js');
            $('.label_check, .label_radio').click(function(){
                setupLabel();
            });
            setupLabel(); 
        });
</script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Version 1 (omitting AJAX)

Well, pretty much you have it done, as far as for adding new items:

```
<form id="ContactForm" action="php/contact.php" method="post">
```

Then, further adjustments should be done at server-side validation and presenting result stage:

```
/* Errors exist */
if($this->countErrors() > 0){
    $json = array(
        'result' => -1, 
        'errors' => array(
                        array('name' => 'contactpersoon'    ,'value' => $this->error_value('contactpersoon')),
                        array('name' => 'bedrijfsnaam'  ,'value' => $this->error_value('bedrijfsnaam')),
                        array('name' => 'email'     ,'value' => $this->error_value('email')),                               
                        array('name' => 'telefoon'  ,'value' => $this->error_value('telefoon')),
                        array('name' => 'vraag1_antwoorden' ,'value' => $this->error_value('vraag1_antwoorden')),
                        array('name' => 'vraag2_antwoorden' ,'value' => $this->error_value('vraag2_antwoorden')),
                    )
        );

    // The code below is an example and was not tested
    // you have to do similar thing for "insert into db" section

    echo("<ol>");
    echo("Please correct the followin errors:")
    foreach ($json['errors'] as $item) {
        echo("<li>".$item['value']."</li>");
    }
    echo("</ol>");
}
/* No errors, insert in db*/
else{
    if(($ret = $this->db->dbNewMessage($contactpersoon, $bedrijfsnaam, $email, $telefoon, $vraag1_antwoorden, $vraag2_antwoorden)) > 0){
        $json = array('result'      => 1); 
        if(SEND_EMAIL)
            $this->sendEmail($contactpersoon,$bedrijfsnaam,$email,$telefoon,$vraag1_antwoorden,$vraag2_antwoorden);

        //the code below is an example, it includes result.php file
        include('result.php');

    }   
    else
        $json = array('result'      => -2); /* something went wrong in database insertion  */
    $encoded = json_encode($json);
    echo $encoded;
    unset($encoded);
}
```

Hints:

1. You don't need JSON here.
2. If you want to keep it simple, just echo HTML with errors or inserted data, where $encoded = json_encode($json) variable gets assigned (both cases, if and else).
3. Make sure, that HTML form action points to you contact.php file.
4. Then, result.php won't be needed.
5. Major disadvantage is that reloading your page will keep adding new contact info if it's not checked at server-side validation.

## Version 2 (displaying errors to your users)

This case will require you to redesign flow of your form, and this is what we want to achieve:
1. A form is presented to your user (form.php).
2. User fills out form (form.php).
3. Form is being submitted (form.php, data is being sent to form.php).
4a. Form is valid, insert data to database and present result page (form.php, then result php), OR
4b. Form is invalid, present errors to user (form.php, submit will bring user back to point 3).

Therefore:
Form code you posted has to be adjusted:
1. First, put your current php/contact.php file's contents on top of it.
2. Then, each table row containing form input field has to be adjusted to present errors that were made.
3. If-else block has to be adjusted to have header("Location: "); to produce redirect to result page.

So, it'll be somewhere along the following.

form.php (code wasn't tested but should have no semantic errors, you should put your html and meta definitions just after '?>' and before ''):

```
<?php
require_once("db.php");                 /* Database Class */
require_once('utils/is_email.php');     /* Email Validation Script */

/* Handle Ajax Request */
if(isset($_POST['newcontact'])){
    $contact = new Contact();
    //We'll refer to that later on, to display errors.
    //unset($contact);
}
else{
    //header('Location: ../result.php');
}

/* Class Contact */
class Contact{

    private $db;                        /* the database obj */

    //private $errors         = array();  /* holds error messages */
    //we have to init $errors array, as otherwise form will produce errors on missing array entry
    private $errors = array(            /* holds error messages */
                'bedrijfsnaam' => '',
                'email' => '',
                'telefoon' => '',
                'vraag1_antwoorden' => '',
                'vraag2_antwoorden' => ''
            );


    private $num_errors;                /* number of errors in submitted form */

    public function __construct(){
        $this->db = new DB();
        if(isset($_POST['newcontact']))
            $this->processNewMessage();
        /* We don't need this anymore
         * 
        else
            header('Location: ../result.php');*/
    }

    public function processNewMessage(){

        $contactpersoon     = $_POST['contactpersoon'];     
        $bedrijfsnaam       = $_POST['bedrijfsnaam'];
        $telefoon           = $_POST['telefoon'];
        $email              = $_POST['email'];
        $vraag1_antwoorden  = $_POST['vraag1_antwoorden'];
        $vraag2_antwoorden  = $_POST['vraag2_antwoorden'];


        /* Server Side Data Validation */

        /* Contactpersoon Validation */
        if(!$contactpersoon || mb_strlen($contactpersoon = trim($contactpersoon)) == 0)
            $this->setError('contactpersoon', 'Vul uw contactpersoon in');
        else if(mb_strlen(trim($contactpersoon)) > 120)
            $this->setError('contactpersoon', 'Te lang! 120 karakters max.');

        /* Bedrijfsnaam Validation */
            if(!$bedrijfsnaam || mb_strlen($bedrijfsnaam = trim($bedrijfsnaam)) == 0)
            $this->setError('bedrijfsnaam', 'Vul uw bedrijfsnaam in');
        else if(mb_strlen(trim($bedrijfsnaam)) > 120)
            $this->setError('bedrijfsnaam', 'Te lang! 120 karakters max.');

            /* Telefoon Validation */
            if(!$telefoon || mb_strlen($telefoon = trim($telefoon)) == 0)
            $this->setError('telefoon', 'Vul uw telefoonnummer in');
        else if(mb_strlen(trim($telefoon)) > 120)
            $this->setError('telefoon', 'Te lang! 120 karakters max.');

            /* Vraag 1 Validation */
            if(!$vraag1_antwoorden || mb_strlen($vraag1_antwoorden = trim($vraag1_antwoorden)) == 0)
            $this->setError('vraag1_antwoorden', 'Selecteer een antwoord a.u.b.');

            /* Vraag 2 Validation */
            if(!$vraag2_antwoorden || mb_strlen($vraag2_antwoorden = trim($vraag2_antwoorden)) == 0)
            $this->setError('vraag2_antwoorden', 'Selecteer een antwoord a.u.b.');

            /* Email Validation */
        if(!$email || mb_strlen($email = trim($email)) == 0)
            $this->setError('email','Vul uw e-mail in');
        else{
            if(!is_email($email))
                $this->setError('email', 'Vul een correct email adres in');
            else if(mb_strlen($email) > 120)
                $this->setError('email', 'Te lang! 120 karakters max.');
        }

        /* Errors exist */
        /*if($this->countErrors() > 0){
            $json = array(
                'result' => -1, 
                'errors' => array(
                                array('name' => 'contactpersoon'    ,'value' => $this->error_value('contactpersoon')),
                                array('name' => 'bedrijfsnaam'  ,'value' => $this->error_value('bedrijfsnaam')),
                                array('name' => 'email'     ,'value' => $this->error_value('email')),                               
                                array('name' => 'telefoon'  ,'value' => $this->error_value('telefoon')),
                                array('name' => 'vraag1_antwoorden' ,'value' => $this->error_value('vraag1_antwoorden')),
                                array('name' => 'vraag2_antwoorden' ,'value' => $this->error_value('vraag2_antwoorden')),
                            )
                );
        }
        /* No errors, insert in db
        else*/
        if($this->countErrors() == 0) {
            if(($ret = $this->db->dbNewMessage($contactpersoon, $bedrijfsnaam, $email, $telefoon, $vraag1_antwoorden, $vraag2_antwoorden)) > 0){
                //$json = array('result'         => 1);
                if(SEND_EMAIL)
                    $this->sendEmail($contactpersoon,$bedrijfsnaam,$email,$telefoon,$vraag1_antwoorden,$vraag2_antwoorden);

                //This is for relocating to successful result page
                header('Location: ../result.php');
            } else {   
                // else
                //    $json = array('result'      => -2); /* something went wrong in database insertion  */

                //This will need special treatment. You have to prepare an errorpage
                //for database-related issues.
                header("Location: database-error.html");
            }

            /*$encoded = json_encode($json);
            echo $encoded;
            unset($encoded);*/
        }
    }

    public function sendEmail($contactpersoon,$bedrijfsnaam,$email,$telefoon,$vraag1_antwoorden,$vraag2_antwoorden){
        /* Just format the email text the way you want ... */
        $message_body   = "<div style=\"font-size:12px; font-weight:normal;\">Hallo,<br><br>"
                                    ."Het volgende bedrijf heeft zich zojuist aangemeld:</div><br>"
                                    ."<table cellpadding=\"1\" cellspacing=\"1\" width=\"550px\"><tr><td style=\"font-size:12px; color:#000000\">Bedrijfsnaam:</td><td style=\"font-size:12px; color:#000000\">".$bedrijfsnaam."</td></tr><tr><td style=\"font-size:12px; color:#000000\">Contactpersoon:</td><td style=\"font-size:12px; color:#000000\">".$contactpersoon."</td></tr><tr><td style=\"font-size:12px; color:#000000\">Telefoonnummer:</td><td style=\"font-size:12px; color:#000000\">".$telefoon."</td></tr><tr><td style=\"font-size:12px; color:#000000\">E-mail:</td><td style=\"font-size:12px; color:#000000\">".$email."</td></tr><tr><td style=\"font-size:12px; color:#000000\">Antwoord vraag 1:</td><td style=\"font-size:12px; color:#000000\">".$vraag1_antwoorden."</td></tr><tr><td style=\"font-size:12px; color:#000000\">Antwoord vraag 2:</td><td style=\"font-size:12px; color:#000000\">".$vraag2_antwoorden."</td></tr></table><br>";

            // Geef GELDIGE adressen op
            // Een korte benaming voor jouw website
            $website_naam = 'Aanmelding';
            // Jouw eigen geldige emailadres
            $eigen_emailadres = 'EMAIL';
            // Een geldig emailadres voor errors
            $error_emailadres = 'EMAIL';
            // De naam van de verzender
            $naam_verzender = ''.$bedrijfsnaam.'';
            // Het geldige emailadres van de afzender
            $email_verzender = ''.$email.'';
            // Een geldig emailadres of helemaal leeg laten
            $bcc_emailadres = '';
            // HTML mail? True/False
            $html = true;

            // De headers samenstellen
            $headers     = 'From: ' . $website_naam . ' <' . $eigen_emailadres . '>' . PHP_EOL;
            $headers    .= 'Reply-To: ' . $naam_verzender . ' <' . $email_verzender . '>' . PHP_EOL;
            $headers    .= 'Return-Path: Mail-Error <' . $error_emailadres . '>' . PHP_EOL;
            $headers    .= ($bcc_emailadres != '') ? 'Bcc: ' . $bcc_emailadres . PHP_EOL : '';
            $headers    .= 'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion() . PHP_EOL;
            $headers    .= 'X-Priority: Normal' . PHP_EOL;
            $headers    .= ($html) ? 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . PHP_EOL : '';
            $headers    .= ($html) ? 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . PHP_EOL : '';


            mail(EMAIL_TO,MESSAGE_SUBJECT,$message_body,$headers);

    }

    public function setError($field, $errmsg){
        $this->errors[$field]   = $errmsg;
        $this->num_errors       = count($this->errors);
    }

    public function error_value($field){
        if(array_key_exists($field,$this->errors))
            return $this->errors[$field];
        else
            return '';
    }

    public function countErrors(){
        return $this->num_errors;
    }
};
?><table>
<form id="ContactForm" action="php/contact.php" method="post">
<tr class="rij_contactpersoon">
    <td class="left_td">Contactpersoon</td>
    <td>
        <input id="contactpersoon" name="contactpersoon" class="inplaceError" maxlength="120" type="text" class="error" autocomplete="off" onFocus="window.scrollTo(0, 0);"/>
        <span class="error" style="display:none; margin-left:40px;">
            <!-- You have to repeat that for every input field below. -->
            <?php echo($contact->error_value('contactpersoon')) ?>
        </span>
    </td>
</tr>



<tr class="rij_bedrijf">
<td class="left_td">Bedrijfsnaam</td><td><input id="bedrijfsnaam" name="bedrijfsnaam" class="inplaceError" maxlength="120" type="text" autocomplete="off" onFocus="window.scrollTo(0, 0);"/><span class="error" style="display:none; margin-left:40px;"></span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="left_td">E-mail</td><td><input id="email" name="email" class="inplaceError" maxlength="120" type="text" autocomplete="off" onFocus="window.scrollTo(0, 0);"/><span class="error" style="display:none; margin-left:40px;"></span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="left_td">Telefoonnummer</td><td><input id="telefoon" name="telefoon" class="inplaceError" maxlength="120" type="text" autocomplete="off" onFocus="window.scrollTo(0, 0);"/><span class="error" style="display:none; margin-left:40px;"></span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="left_td">Question 1</td><td><div class="sizer"><label class="label_radio" for="vraag1_A"><input name="vraag1_antwoorden" id="vraag1_A" value="A" type="radio" />A) 10 Ohm</label><label class="label_radio" for="vraag1_B"><input name="vraag1_antwoorden" id="vraag1_B" value="B" type="radio" />B) 1 Ohm</label><label class="label_radio" for="vraag1_C"><input name="vraag1_antwoorden" id="vraag1_C" value="C" type="radio" />C) 0,1 Ohm</label><label class="label_radio" for="vraag1_D"><input name="vraag1_antwoorden" id="vraag1_D" value="D" type="radio" />D) Geen eis</label></div><span id="vraag1_antwoorden" class="foutmelding_quiz" style="display:none;"></span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="left_td">Question 2</td><td><div class="sizer"><label class="label_radio" for="vraag2_A"><input name="vraag2_antwoorden" id="vraag2_A" value="A" type="radio" />A) 10 Ohm</label><label class="label_radio" for="vraag2_B"><input name="vraag2_antwoorden" id="vraag2_B" value="B" type="radio" />B) 1 Ohm</label><label class="label_radio" for="vraag2_C"><input name="vraag2_antwoorden" id="vraag2_C" value="C" type="radio" />C) 0,1 Ohm</label><label class="label_radio" for="vraag2_D"><input name="vraag2_antwoorden" id="vraag2_D" value="D" type="radio" />D) Geen eis</label></div><span id="vraag2_antwoorden" class="foutmelding_quiz" style="display:none;"></span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="left_td"></td><td><input type="button" class="button_verzenden black" id="send" value="VERSTUUR" /><input type="hidden" id="newcontact" name="newcontact" value="1"></input></form>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Hello Michal, thanks for this detailed answer, where do I need to put the server side validation, in the contact.php file? Can you show me an example because i'm a bit confused with the whole AJAX thing.

Comment: Server side validation is there, just add action='php/contact.php' method='post' to your form file and you'll see where to make changes.

Comment: {"result":1} This is the response I am getting back from my browser, that is the part you mentioned above from contact.php

Can I just delete certain rows from this code?

Comment: {"result": 1} comes from operations in else block, after /* No errors, insert in db*/. You have to display your own message here, as previously, JSON message was interpreted by JavaScript. So, you might want to put your result.php code here.

Comment: I put the code above, but it does not work, can you show me where I need to delete of mention certain elements regarding result.php? How do I replace the JSON with HTML like you mentioned?

Comment: I somehow replaced JSON with foreach loop, try if it works for you.

Comment: Hee Michal, I updated it a lit bit, the validation works, but do you know how I can say that the errors should be displayed next to the form field where the error comes from and not on a blank page

Comment: Well, you'd have to put echo next to each input field in your form thingie. You don't seem to be a programmer, do you? ;)

Comment: Trying hard haha, can you please help me with this?

Comment: This is what I have now next to the fields: <td class="left_td">Contactpersoon</td><td><input id="contactpersoon" name="contactpersoon" class="inplaceError" maxlength="120" type="text" class="error" autocomplete="off" onFocus="window.scrollTo(0, 0);"/><span class="error" style="display:none; margin-left:40px;"></span></td>

Comment: Do I also need to change the form action in order to see the echo next to the field?

Comment: Well, action parameter means "send this form to that file". So, in this case, I think that the easiest way

Comment: Oke so the action parameter now stands to php/contact.php. But how do I mention with the contact.php that the error should be displayed next to the form? Should I use a header function?

Comment: Ok, first: action parameter determines page to send requests to. If you want to have an error message next to field it applies to, action should point to itself (a bit more of rebuilding here). I'll add updated version soon.

Comment: Djenkuje Michal, that would really help me!

Comment: I Updated the code above with my full script. The input fields disappear after the first <span> error. Do you know why?